# Get Which iOS Frameworks are Available?

Tags: ios

I'm writing a static library for iOS.  I want to programmatically figure out if CoreLocation is added to the project, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"CLLocationManager"))
{
    NSLog(@"CoreLocation is available");
}
```

Would do it. [NSClassFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString) takes an NSString and checks whether there's a class of that name currently available in the runtime. If so then it returns the `Class` object, otherwise it returns nil. The if statement there effectively compares to nil.

So, the logic you're applying is "does a class called CLLocationManager currently exist?", which is a proxy for checking that CoreLocation is loaded because it's one of the fundamental classes to that framework.

Comment: Thanks Tommy!  Is there any way I could tell if an #import<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> would fail?

Comment: Not really - that's a compile-time directive. So it'll fail or succeed based on whether the compiler can find the file. What you may want to do is import the header without linking to the library, then use compile-time checks on whether you can use the library ala official advice on dealing with APIs that turn up only in later versions of iOS. Does that sound like it would solve your problem?